# rsync through ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, rsync, ssh-tunnel

I want to rsync to a cluster node to which I usually connect passing through another system:

Say I connect first to

```
  ssh user@bridge
```

and from there to

```
  ssh user@clusternode
```

Now I want to rsync from my workstation to clusternode. I do the following:

- I open a ssh tunnel

  ```
  ssh -L8000:clusternode:8000 user@bridge
  ```
- I rsync from my workstation to clusternode

  ```
  rsync -e "ssh -p8000" source user@localhost:destination
  ```

and it does not work, I get

```
 ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Why does it not work? What do I have to do?

---

I have found a lot of information here:

http://toddharris.net/blog/2005/10/23/rsyncing-through-an-ssh-tunnel/

I think to understand that my problem is the second authentication between the bridge and the destination, so I changed to method 2 that is also not very elegant, but it works. I would like to try method 3, but I don't know how to configure a rsync daemon

Comment: Try using the -v (or -vvv) option to ssh command:  `rsync -e "ssh -vvv -p8000" source user@localhost:destination` to enable the verbose ssh logging, the error is almost always in there.

Comment: You can set up a proxy to be used for your cluster node (see e.g. https://rsync.samba.org/firewall.html, esp. Method 2), and then use rsync without explicitly specifying a proxy.

Comment: A better solution than given in the answers below: https://puppet.com/blog/speed-up-ssh-by-reusing-connections

Comment: Why is this question off-topic?

Comment: @rashid "We don’t allow questions about professional server or networking-related infrastructure administration on Stack Overflow. You can edit the question so it’s on-topic for Stack Overflow or post a new one on Server Fault."

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Here's what worked for me.

I run a command in the background to tunnel to the remote host:

```
 ssh -N -L 2222:remote.example.com:22 bridge.example.com&
```

then I rsync to localhost like this:

```
rsync -auve "ssh -p 2222" . me@localhost:/some/path
```

Comment: You have to remove the last character ``&`` on the first command to enter the password.

Answer (score 92):

Try this one-liner:

```
rsync -av -e "ssh -A root@proxy ssh" ./src root@target:/dst
```

Comment: That one liner is perfect, since I don't want to open a persistent tunnel.  Thanks!

Comment: one line solution would be nice, but it doesn't work for me. I get
"Host key verification failed.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c(452) [sender=2.6.9]"
I think it is because it only asks me the password for the bridge and it never asks me the password for the target (they both have a password)

Comment: @simona, if you configured an SSH key instead of a password, this would be moot (the `-A` forwards the agent connection used to access in-memory SSH keys).

Comment: But what if we can't set up SSH keys? Is it possible to do a one liner and provide a password for both servers?

Comment: Try it without the `-A` and I suspect you would just get asked for the passwords. It's worth a try. I just was successful without the `-A`, but I have keys set up.

Comment: I found that using `rsync -av -e "ssh -A user@proxy ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"` didn't fail with `Host key verification failed`. This will only work if the host key has never been seen before, in case it has changed add `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` (not recommended unless you know why it changed).

Comment: @abalter trying without -A didn't help for me

Answer (score 5):

You should connect to the port 22 of clusternode, so the tunnel should look like

```
ssh -L localhost:8000:clusternode:22 user@bridge
```